# What information does Apple collect when an iPad sends "advanced" log data?

Tags: ios, privacy

Apple support contacted me regarding an issue I had with an iPad. They requested diagnostic data which I agreed to (in the Privacy -> Analytics).  Then right after the diagnostic data was sent, another window popped up that requested more "advanced" logs and in the description it said it would contain, among other things, my email addresses, file paths, etc. The process took a while and a message warned that the iPad may become slow during this process. At the end it compressed the data and uploaded it to Apple. I couldn't see what was being uploaded but judging from the time it took, I think it was tens of megabytes  (maybe 50~80MB after compression).

Unfortunately I did not take a screenshot thinking I would be able to find this topic online on Apple's web site. But I can't see any document that describes what data is exactly collected or for how long it is retained. Does Apple describe this "advanced" data collection anywhere?

Comment: Let’s hope it was Apple... or you may have sent all your passwords etc to someone.

Comment: @SolarMike It was Apple. It was with regards to an issue I raised a few days ago; it was from an Apple number; and I believe only Apple can activate this special button in Settings -> Privacy -> Analytics that shares diagnostic data with Apple.